# dispay pointer as text label ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've searched parse docs and couldn't figure this out. I have a user class, and then a player class (called Junkballer). Within the player class, I have a score that's a number. I'm trying to display the score of each player in the text label.

It's just displaying zero.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    PFQuery *groundstrokeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Junkballer"];
    [groundstrokeQuery whereKey:@"groundstrokes" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    //[groundstrokeQuery includeKey:@"groundstrokes"];
    [groundstrokeQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The count request succeeded. Log the count
            NSLog(@"You have hit %d groundstrokes!", count);
            self.groundStrokes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
        } else {
            // The request failed
        }
    }];






}
```

Comment: what does your debugger say? Maybe count is always zero?

Comment: 0x292e9fb4 <+144>: mov    r0, r5

Comment: It sounds -- from the name -- as if the completion block is executed in the background.  What if you dispatch your UI update to the main thread?

Comment: yes do: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /*your UI code */ });